# How to test if a react component has been rendered from a switch state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, chai

I have a file called ModalContainer which renders child components with a switch statement based on the props.

```
render() {
    let visibleElement = null;
    switch (this.props.modal) {
      case constants.SEARCH_AND_HIGHLIGHT_MODAL:
        visibleElement = <SearchAndHighlightModal/>;
        break;
      case constants.SAVE_SNIPPET_MODAL:
        visibleElement = <SaveSnippetModal/>;
        break;
      case constants.SNIPPET_SAVED_MODAL:
        visibleElement = <SnippetSavedModal/>;
        break;
      case constants.SAVE_SEARCH_MODAL:
        visibleElement = <SaveSearchModal/>;
        break;
      default visibleElement = null;
```

I'm mounting the ModalComponent and passing in props but when I try to console log the output I get `ReactWrapper {}` which I can't use for the assertion test.

Here is my test

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import sinonTest from 'sinon-test';
import {Map} from 'immutable';
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount, configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {mockStore} from '../test_helper';

//import {constants} from '../src/react/constants/constants.js';

import {ModalContainer} from '../../src/react/ModalContainer/ModalContainer';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Modal Container - Modal Container JSX', () => {

  describe('Render from switch case', () => {

    const fakeStore = mockStore(Map({}));

    it('Render Search And Highlight Modal', () => {

      const props = {
        constants: {
          SEARCH_AND_HIGHLIGHT_MODAL: 'search-and-highlight'
        }
      }

      const wrapper = mount(<ModalContainer store={fakeStore}
                                            visible={false}
                                            modal={false}
                                            metaData={null}
                                            {...props}
      />);
      //const visibleElement = wrapper.find();
      //const myProps = wrapper.props();
      console.log(wrapper.find('SearchAndHighlightModal'));

      //expect(wrapper.find('SearchAndHighlightModal')).to.have.lengthOf(1);

    });

  });

});
```

I have tested each of the child components in separate test cases and just need to test this part of the file.
Thanks

Comment: You can do `shallow` render and test with `dive` and `find`. find can search using component class.

Comment: Here is what I used for testing if ABC component renders ChildComponent correctly.

`const content = component.find(ABC).dive().dive().find(ChildComponent); expect(content.exists()).toEqual(true);`

Comment: Additionally, to debug easily you use `.debug()` on any of the shallow mounted component to see what it holds while testing.

Comment: Where do you import mount from?

Comment: Hi, i have changed my console log to: ```console.log(wrapper.find('SearchAndHighlightModal').dive());```
But now I get the error ```Method "dive" is meant to be run on 1 node.0 found instead```

Comment: @AvinKavish I import mount from 'enzyme'

Comment: Have you tried passing the class/function in? `wrapper.find(SearchAndHighlightModal)`

Comment: @AvinKavish Yes, but when console logging the output I get ```ReactWrapper {}``` which I can't use to test.

Answer (score 1):

To test if child component is correctly rendered you can follow the pattern given below:

```
import {shallow} from "enzyme/build";
import ThemeProvider from "./mock-themeprovider";
import React from "react";
import ParentComponent from "./ParentComponent";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

it("Does component renders child component correctly based on type?", () => {
    const component = shallow(<ThemeProvider value="primary">
        <ParentComponent
            type={1} //for type 1 assuming it renders ChildComponent
        />
    </ThemeProvider>);
    console.log(component.debug());
    const content = component.find(ParentComponent).dive().dive().find(ChildComponent);
    expect(content.exists()).toEqual(true);
});
```

You may have to do multiple `.dive()` or not even once, based on your implementation of ParentComponent.

To quickly see the tree while writing test cases `.debug()` on shallow method saves a lot of time!!!

Comment: ThemeProvider is added to example to show a case where you might need to add container components/theme provider components/internationalization providers. You can safely skip ThemeProvider.